# youtube audio is always playing in Android webview when I press back button

Tags: android, audio, webview, youtube

I have a `WebView` in a `Fragment` with a youtube video. When I press back button the youtube audio continues playing:

```
View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment, container, false );
configView( view );


view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            if ( null != webView )
            {
                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

On the other hand, when I put the app on background the `onPause()` event works correctly:

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if ( null != webView )
    {
        webView.loadUrl( "about:blank" );
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work when I press back button? Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

When a Youtube video is playing, the back button event belong to the webview. The fragment is not handling this event. 
The solution is:

```
webView.setOnKeyListener( new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
        {
            if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
            {
                if ( null != webView )
                {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                    webView.destroy();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

a more general approach:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        WebView.class.getMethod("onResume").invoke(wvBorwser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        WebView.class.getMethod("onPause").invoke(wvBorwser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```